# Error using Ksoap2 library in Android

Tags: android, jar, ksoap2, android-ksoap2

I'm trying to use KSoap2 library.
I put the file Ksoap2-android-assembly-2.5.7-jar-with-dependencies.jar in the directory workspace > myproject > libs

Then I setted it in build path. (libraries)

I have error just when I run the application:

```
 11-27 10:32:56.260: E/dalvikvm(1593): Could not find class 'org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject', referenced from method
```

associated to this code line:

```
 SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);
```

I tried also with the steps suggested in this thread [exception while using ksoap2 library for android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5708624/exception-while-using-ksoap2-library-for-android)
whitout success

Comment: Try a newest version ksoap2: http://ksoap2-android.googlecode.com/svn/m2-repo/com/google/code/ksoap2-android/ksoap2-android-assembly/3.0.0-RC.4/ksoap2-android-assembly-3.0.0-RC.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar

Comment: I know, but I created this application a year ago, and everything worked well. Why would not it work this time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem checking checkbox on kosoap2 library in Java Build Path options, Order And Export tab.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use SOAP parsing then try using my this code on stack.
here is a link
[Send data from Android to Web Service (via SOAP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13514384/send-data-from-android-to-web-service-via-soap/13523246#13523246)

Answer (score 1):

You should use a right ksoap library. What is version android that you're using?

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092712/ksoap-android-soap-client

Comment: I created this application a year ago, and everything worked well. I was using the version 2.5.7